# Which datatype is best for saving images in database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using PhpMyadmin to create database but I don't know datatype of images in database.

Comment: It depends on your database engine, i.e. MySQL, Postgres etc. Often, types like BLOB are used to store binary data. But probably more efficient way would be to store files in special storages (local filesystem or aws s3, or something else) and put only file paths to the database. In such case varchar type will do.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely you can use **BLOB** datatype to store images in the database

Yes, you can store images in the database, but it's not advisable in my opinion, and it's not general practice.

A general practice is to store images in directories on the file system and store references to the images in the database. e.g. path to the image,the image name, etc.. Or alternatively, you may even store images on a content delivery network (CDN) or numerous hosts across some great expanse of physical territory, and store references to access those resources in the database.

Images can get quite large, greater than 1MB. And so storing images in a database can potentially put unnecessary load on your database and the network between your database and your web server if they're on different hosts.

Comment: How about TINYINT?

Comment: What about tinyint, its used to store a tiny number.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit bad in English, thanks for your answer.

Comment: you definitely cant use tinyint for storing images.following document will help you to understand mysql datatypes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html

Comment: let me know if you need any help